# SQL Server Query for Many to Many Relationship - how to query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, many-to-many, pivot

This is an update to my previous question : [Many to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644293/sql-server-query-for-many-to-many-relationship/14644500#comment21191340_14644500)

The previous solution works fine, but now I want tgo improve the results a little bit. I´d like to have all the wavelength values in one row.

So instead of the following result :

```
DateTimeID  Wavelength  SensorID
11435   1581,665    334
11435   1515,166    334
11435   1518,286    335
```

I'd like to have something similar to this:

```
DateTimeID  Wavelength1 Wavelength2  SensorID
11435   1581,665    1515,166     334
11435   1518,286                 335
```

Comment: What RDMS? SQL Server, Db2, Oracle? and version? Guessing SQL Server since previous post tagged it.

Comment: Is one wave length depending on the SensorID?

Comment: Your example doesn't match the text. The example has 3 wavelengths with the same id spread over 2 rows.

Comment: Its SQL Server 2008 Express edition.

Comment: But according to the relationship in my previous post you can see, that many Wavelengths can be related to one SensorID. In most cases there's only 1, but in some cases 2 (sensorID 334)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the following which applies a `row_number()` to the records:

```
select DateTimeID,
  [1] as Wavelength1, 
  [2] as Wavelength2,
  SensorId
from
(
  select [DateTimeID], [Wavelength], [SensorID],
    row_number() over(partition by DateTimeID, SensorId
                      order by DateTimeID) rn
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  max(Wavelength)
  for rn in ([1], [2])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0877c/2).

If you will have an unknown number of `wavelength` values, then you can use dynamic SQL to generate this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME('Wavelength'+cast(rn as varchar(50))) 
                    from
                    (
                      select row_number() over(partition by DateTimeID, SensorId
                                              order by DateTimeID) rn
                      from yourtable
                    ) src
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT DateTimeID,' + @cols + ', SensorId  from 
             (
                select [DateTimeID], [Wavelength], [SensorID],
                  ''Wavelength''+cast(row_number() over(partition by DateTimeID, SensorId
                                        order by DateTimeID) as varchar(50)) rn
                from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(Wavelength)
                for rn in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0877c/8)

Comment: Thank You! Why are you using the max function?

Comment: @patex1987 `pivot` requires an aggregate function. Since the `wavelength` is a string, then you will need to use `min` or `max`.

Comment: @patex1987 I added a dynamic sql version in the event you have an unknown number of values that you need to transform into columns. :)

Comment: `+1` in terms of pivoting question, whew, you're awesome! `:D`