# Different fields for every user on a view in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am going to make an application in which every user have its own specification .

Suppose i have a table which have following fields

**Data**
    Id
    Name
    Date

Now one user say that i need a `description` field where i can put my description

other user comes and says that i need two new fields `IsVerified , IsLocal` .

Now my question is that how peoples manage this kind of applications .

At view side how can we determine that which fields should be rendered for current visiting user .

and how to manage same scenario in database .

What i think for database end , we can put all possible fields in table but don't know that is this apparoach is good or not

So please give me idea how to manage that type of application and it will be very helping if anyone gives a link to example .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Many to many relationship

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644293/sql-server-query-for-many-to-many-relationship

Answer (score 2):

Create seperate table for user & fields like

```
Table: User
UserId Name Date

Table: Field
FieldId UserId Name Value
```

here Field table contains all user fields, we can get perticuler user field by UserId.

may this help to you..

Answer (score 0):

In an asp.net setting, I would use the profile provider for this kind of needs.
You can implement your own by inheriting from ProfileBase.

Documentation and examples (scroll down) here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.profilebase.aspx

For your particular need, you could use a Hashtable, or even a dictionary, the user can store anything he/she wants, on any given key. Hashtables and Dictionaries needs to be serialized as binary.

```
[SettingsAllowAnonymous(false), SettingsSerializeAs(SettingsSerializeAs.Binary)]
[ProfileProvider("AspNetSqlProfileProvider")]
public Hashtable Fields
{
get
{
return base["Fields"] as Hashtable;
}
set
{
base["Fields"] = value;
Save();
}
}
```